In camel-package-maven-plugin for goal generate-dsl-endpoint for <endpointFactoriesPackageName> property not working in 4.6 camel
So I am trying to generate the DSL endpoint & component classes as a separate package in the genearted resource and store them and use them in tests. So I have used camel-package-maven-plugin with camel 4.6 (Along with several others like camel-component-maven-plugin, maven-compiler, build-helper-maven (codehaus), maven-source, jacoco maven, properties-maven, maven antrun, maven clean plugins). I am able to do this successfully with Camel 3.18.1 (Spring Boot 2.7) using configuration fields   in the pom for camel-package-maven-plugin.
But now I have upgraded to Camel 4.6 (Spring Boot 3.3). but now the package name it is generating is default that is : org.apache.camel.builder.endpoint. Though the job of the properties   is to override the default name with the params I passed ( com.test.camel.endpoint.dsl ). But it is not overriding in camel 4.6. But was working in 3.18. So can anyone help on how to do this. I must override the package to use it in tests.
This is the config
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-endpoint-dsl</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate-endpoint-dsl</goal>
                <goal>generate-component-dsl</goal>
                <goal>generate-others-list</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <jsonDir>${project.build.directory}/src/generated/resources/dsl</jsonDir>
                <endpointFactoriesPackageName>com.test.camel.endpoint</endpointFactoriesPackageName>
                <componentFactoriesPackageName>com.test.camel.endpoint.dsl</componentFactoriesPackageName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

I want the dsl component & dsl enpdoint class to be generated as .class in a specified directory like generated resource with the mentioned package name as I provided in config.
It is generating the default package name.
